# Nothing displaying when connecting Pi 2B to TV

Tags: pi-2

I have a **Raspberry Pi 2B** and whenever I try to connect to my TV so I can use the Pi, nothing shows up. It is just a black screen... nothing else.
I am using HDMI, and one light is green, and one is red.
Am I doing anything wrong? Why won't it turn on?
I have tried a lot, and I think it's the Pi that's faulty. But I don't want to swap it over. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: You may want to edit your question to mention that yo are connecting via HDMI, have tried multiple cables and thaat both the LEDs are on and not blinking.

Comment: Is the green one flashing? If not, then you have no MicroSD or the MicroSD doesn't contain the necessary boot data.

Comment: Ditto.  Solid green means it rejected the SD card; nothing will ever appear on the screen.

Comment: Have you even inserted a bootable SD Card? It doesn't come with an OS out of the box!

Comment: Well, except if you ordered it with an NOOBS SD Card. I'm typing this on a Raspberry Pi 2 B, same model as yours.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this, add the following text:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

to the `/flash/config.txt` file. You'll find this in your Raspberry Pi file on the formatted SD card.