# HDMI Output Not Working on Raspberry Pi2, model B

Tags: pi-2, hdmi, setup

I am trying to set up my Raspberry Pi for the first time. I downloaded NOOBS from the Raspberry Pi website, and followed the instructions to format the micro SD card (was fresh out of the package anyway).  I hooked everything up, but both TVs I tried it on simply say that there is no HDMI signal.  I have tried multiple different power supplies.  The red LED on the Pi is solid and the green one is flashing on and off.  I appreciate any help.

Comment: Btw, it is the Raspberry Pi 2, model B

Comment: Take a look at this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40039/nothing-displaying-when-connecting-pi-2b-to-tv/40040#40040

Comment: I have searched through the directories, but cannot find the config.txt file.  I tried creating one, but that didn't do anything.  I'm thinking I might of did something wrong with the raspbian files.

Comment: What OS is your PC running (the one where you  made the SD Card)? Does it have a raspberry pi folder?

Comment: You may also want to check this http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern

Comment: I'm running windows 10 pro.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33520/discussion-between-green-plasma-and-steve-robillard).